# Windows Mobile application can be deployed in an Emulator, but not in device

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, emulation

I am developing a Windows Mobile app in VS 2005 to be deployed in a Windows Mobile 6.1 device.
My application can be deployed in an emulator, but can't be deployed in the device.

What can be the reason?

Any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: could you add more specifics? What version of compact framework are you targeting, what version of windows mobile is your emulator running, how are you deploying the app to your device, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: .NET Framework is 2.0, I am using Windows Mobile 6 Classic or Professional emulator.

Comment: My error message is "Connection failed. Server execution failed"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the drivers for the device correctly installed.
Have you tried adding your device to debug into it ?

Comment: Yes and I can't do debugging and deployment.

Comment: Try going to your device Start -> Settings -> Connections -> USB to PC then  it will show an option  "Enable advanced network functionality" , DISABLED this and try again.

Comment: So, you have a WMDC connection but cannnot deploy or debug or Remote Connect. Then your VS installtion is impossble to copy over and launch the reqiered components. You may just switch to another target SDK (ie Window Mobile 5) and then try again. If you do not have WM5 SDK installed just go to MS site and download and install it. For debugging etc WM5 SDK connection does not make a difference. If that works or not, you may need to remove and re-install WM6 SDK. Another possibly issue my come from a firewall blocking the remote ports - try with disabled firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ActiveSync or WMDC connection to the device?

Can you launch "Connect to device" in VS Tools menu?

What are your VS device settings? Deployment dir for the project etc.?

Comment: I am having Windows 7 Professional in my PC and I have installed WMDC also and it indicates that the Windows Mobile 6.1 device is connected. But Active Sync could not be installed. Target device is Windows Mobile 6 Professional Device.

Comment: I can launch "Connect to Device" option, when Mobile Device is connected to PC but it does not connect and continuously displaying "Connecting"

Comment: Finally giving me an error message, "Connection failed. Server execution failed".